# How to make typescript transfer .pug file to compiled directory

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, pug

I'm using cloud functions to render an html file to send in an email with pug template engine.

To start, I'm trying to do the following:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as pug from 'pug';

export const renderHTML = functions.https.onRequest(() => {
// Compile the source code
const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile('email.pug');

// Render a set of data
return compiledFunction({
  name: 'Timothy'
});
// "<p>Timothy's Pug source code!</p>"
});
```

However, when running the function, the .pug cannot be found. I suspect this is because it is not carried over in the typescript compilation to js. So, how can I make it go into the lib file without manually putting it there?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put email.pug in the functions folder, not the src folder.  The file path are taken relative to the deployment root, which is functions.  You can use other folders as long as you specify them relative to functions.

Comment: That seems to have worked. However... when I run the function nothings happens, just times out. Do you see anything wrong with the code itself? I think that should work...

Comment: I don't know, I suggest posting a new question with your debugging details.